# Is Json RPC called "JSON" RPC because it returns JSON?

Tags: api, rpc, json-rpc

Is JSON RPC called "JSON" RPC because it returns JSON?

So today I have learnt that there several types of apis. Like REST apis, RPC apis, GraphQL apis and others.

I am familiar with REST apis and I now trying to understand Json RPC? What does the JSON in JSON RPC represent? Does mean the data is returned in Json format? Of you send the request in Json format?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes,

> JSON-RPC is a stateless, light-weight remote procedure call (RPC) protocol. Primarily this specification defines several data structures and the rules around their processing. It is transport agnostic in that the concepts can be used within the same process, over sockets, over http, or in many various message passing environments. It uses JSON (RFC 4627) as data format.

Long answer, you should have just googled this and read the JSON-RPC docs:
https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification